# python3 標準関数に割り込み処理を入れたい

Tags: python, python3

やりたい事はタイトルのままなのですが、具体的には

```
@printの割り込み処理
def interrupt():
    print('割り込み処理')

# あるいは
@割り込み処理
def interrupt():
    if __割り込み元を持っているもの__ == print:
        print('割り込み処理')

print('通常出力')

# 出力
割り込み処理
通常出力
```

みたいな事ができれば良いのですが、上記のような事は出来ますでしょうか？
例ではprintとしていますが、printに限りません。
なお、python3系です。

出来なければ出来ない、という回答がいただけると助かります。
出来ない場合、どういう工夫でそれっぽい事が出来るのか、アイデアをもらえるとそれはそれ嬉しいです。

例えば

```
INTERRUPT = True

@ユーザー関数のprint
def user_print(message, interrupt_flag=INTERRUPT)
    if interrupt_flag:
        interrupt()
    print(message)
```

みたいな方法になるのかな、と漠然と考えています。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

以下は`print`を自前の関数に置き換え、元の組込み`print`の実行前にメッセージを出す例です。

#### [builtins](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/builtins.html) 経由での全体的な置き換え

[builtins](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/builtins.html)モジュール経由で組み込みオブジェクトの名前空間を参照して、自前の関数に置き換える方法です。
この操作を行なうファイルだけでなく、他のモジュールにも影響します。

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 本物の組込みprint関数の値を保存しておく
orig_print = print

# 自前のprint用関数を定義する
def my_print(*args):
    orig_print("# カスタム版printが呼ばれました")   # 追加したい処理
    return orig_print(*args)   # 元のprintの呼び出し

# トップレベル（組込み識別子の名前空間）のprintを自前のものにする
import builtins
builtins.print = my_print

# このファイルでprintという変数は定義されていないので、
# ここでのprintはトップレベル（組込み識別子の名前空間）のprintとなる
# そして、それは上で置き換え済み
print("hello, world")
```

出力:

```
# カスタム版printが呼ばれました
hello, world
```

#### 現在のファイル（モジュール）で`print`を定義

Pythonでは、最初の代入で現在のローカル名前空間内の変数が作られることを利用し、`print`変数に自前の関数を代入してしまいます。
この場合、トップレベル（組込み識別子の名前空間）の`print`はそのままですから、他のモジュールでの`print`の呼び出しには影響しません。

```
print = my_print   # my_print の定義は上を参照
print("hello, world")
```

#### 特定のモジュールの名前空間に `print` を追加

下のように、モジュールに`print`を追加してしまえば、そのモジュール内で`print`が呼び出された際には、これが呼ばれることになります。

```
import module_a
module_a.print = my_print   # my_print の定義は上を参照
```

#### その他

テストやデバッグ目的としては、[`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/ja/dev/library/unittest.mock.html)モジュールも参考になるかと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます、そして今更になってしまってすみません。
当時どこで質問をしたのか分からなくなってしまい、回答を見つける事ができませんでした。

まさに当時欲しかった情報です。プリントデバッグ時に実行するかどうか制御がしたかったのだと思います。
今思えば、こんな複雑な事をしないで`debug_flag`などを使って制御すればよかったのでは？という気がしないでもないですが、質問文に書いてないので読めないですね。大変失礼しました。

ベストアンサーをつけさせていただいたのは「テストやデバッグ目的」だったからです。鋭いエスパーをありがとうございました。
またご相談差し上げる事があるかもしれません。その際はまたよろしくご指導ください。

Answer (score 3):

組み込み関数を上書きしたいというのであれば、[builtinsモジュール](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/builtins.html)を使ってください。

```
# coding: utf-8

import sys
if sys.version_info.major < 3:
    import __builtin__ as builtins
else:
    import builtins

print_original = builtins.__dict__['print']
def print_custom(s):
    print_original('Interrupt.')
    print_original(s)
builtins.__dict__['print'] = print_custom

print('Hello, world!')
```

ただ、注意が必要です。

上書きしたprint関数でprintを呼びだせば、当然再帰的に関数が呼ばれる事になります。
(上記の例では、そのためにオリジナルのprint関数を「print_original」に保存しています)

builtinsモジュールを変更すると、importしたモジュールにも影響を及ぼします。

他にこのようなソースコードは見かけないので、ある意味禁じ手なのかぁ…。

ちなみに、上記のソースコードは、python2では動きません。
おそらく、printが関数ではなく文だからではないかと思いますが。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます、そして今更になってしまってすみません。
当時どこで質問をしたのか分からなくなってしまい、回答を見つける事ができませんでした。

まさに当時欲しかった情報です。プリントデバッグ時に実行するかどうか制御がしたかったのだと思います。
今思えば、こんな複雑な事をしないで`debug_flag`などを使って制御すればよかったのでは？という気がしないでもないですが、質問文に書いてないので読めないですね。大変失礼しました。

Answer (score 1):

[Python でイベント指向のプログラミングを実現する](https://emptypage.jp/notes/pyevent.html)　の記事に書かれている事が、質問者が希望している事ではありませんか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます、そして今更になってしまってすみません。
当時どこで質問をしたのか分からなくなってしまい、回答を見つける事ができませんでした。

まさに当時欲しかった情報です。プリントデバッグ時に実行するかどうか制御がしたかったのだと思います。
今思えば、こんな複雑な事をしないで`debug_flag`などを使って制御すればよかったのでは？という気がしないでもないですが、質問文に書いてないので読めないですね。大変失礼しました。

そして、いただいたリンク先に目を通しましたが、この方法は思いつかなかったです。当時を思い出しながら読ませていただきましたが、こんなテクニックがあるんだと感心しました！とても良い学びになりました。